# using apply on listcolumns in R seems inconsistent

Tags: r, apply, unnest

..or at least inconsistent with my intuition.

I'm trying to extract data from inside a listcolumn using `apply` - in the example I've got a column of tibbles called `eagles`:

```
df1 <- tibble(
  location = c(1,2),
  eagles = list(
    tibble(
      talons = c(2,3,4),
      beaks = c("blue","red","red")),
    tibble(
      talons = c(2,3),
      beaks = c("red","red"))))
```

and extracting the `beaks` values as vectors using `apply`:

```
df1$beakz <- apply(df1, 1, \(x) x$eagles$beaks)
```

which works as expected:

```
> df1
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  location eagles           beakz    
     <dbl> <list>           <list>   
1        1 <tibble [3 x 2]> <chr [3]>
2        2 <tibble [2 x 2]> <chr [2]>
```

However if I add another row to one of the nested tibbles, the `apply` function won't play along anymore:

```
df2 <- tibble(
  location = c(1,2),
  eagles = list(
    tibble(
      talons = c(2,3,4),
      beaks = c("blue","red","red")),
    tibble(
      talons = c(2,3,2),
      beaks = c("red","red","yellow"))))

df2$beakz <- apply(df2, 1, \(x) x$eagles$beaks)
Error:
! Assigned data `apply(df2, 1, function(x) x$eagles$beaks)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 2 rows.
x Assigned data has 3 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

The expected output would be adding a listcolumn `beakz` with two vectors (of length 3) as elements.

Additionally, if both the nested tibbles have two rows only, the apply function does work, but instead of a single new listcolumn, I get two new columns:

```
df3 <- tibble(
   location = c(1,2),
   eagles = list(
     tibble(
       talons = c(2,3),
       beaks = c("blue","red")),
     tibble(
       talons = c(2,3),
       beaks = c("red","red"))))
df3$beakz <- apply(df3, 1, \(x) x$eagles$beaks)
df3
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  location eagles           beakz[,1] [,2] 
     <dbl> <list>           <chr>     <chr>
1        1 <tibble [2 x 2]> blue      red  
2        2 <tibble [2 x 2]> red       red
```

This is a grossly simplified example, but basically, I would expect `apply` to function the same way in all three cases: I would like to extract a column as a vector and bring it up a level. Ideally using `apply`, although I'm sure there are `purrr` ways of doing this. But mainly I would just like to understand why this works this way, because debugging it has not been much fun :lolsob:

(also would appreciate it if someone with enough reputation could add `listcolumn` or `list-column` to the tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `apply()` does not return a list, it returns a 3x2 matrix, which has too many rows to be put into `df2`. To get it to do what you want you could e.g. coerce it to a data frame (to give the columns names) and then to a list. There's probably a more elegant way to do it. But basically `apply()` does not play well with the list-structure of your data, whereas the `purrr` functions do.

```r
apply(df2, 1, \(x) x$eagles$beaks)
#>      [,1]   [,2]    
#> [1,] "blue" "red"   
#> [2,] "red"  "red"   
#> [3,] "red"  "yellow"

class(apply(df2, 1, \(x) x$eagles$beaks))
#> [1] "matrix" "array"

df2$beakz <- as.list(data.frame(apply(df2, 1, \(x) x$eagles$beaks)))

df2
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   location eagles           beakz       
#>      <dbl> <list>           <named list>
#> 1        1 <tibble [3 × 2]> <chr [3]>   
#> 2        2 <tibble [3 × 2]> <chr [3]>

df2$beakz
#> $X1
#> [1] "blue" "red"  "red" 
#> 
#> $X2
#> [1] "red"    "red"    "yellow"
```

Answer (score 1):

Purely for reference (not debugging OP), `purrr` works without issue:

```r
library(purrr)

> mutate(df1, beaks=map(eagles, ~ .x$beaks))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  location eagles           beaks    
     <dbl> <list>           <list>   
1        1 <tibble [3 × 2]> <chr [3]>
2        2 <tibble [2 × 2]> <chr [2]>

> mutate(df2, beaks=map(eagles, ~ .x$beaks))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  location eagles           beaks    
     <dbl> <list>           <list>   
1        1 <tibble [3 × 2]> <chr [3]>
2        2 <tibble [3 × 2]> <chr [3]>

> mutate(df3, beaks=map(eagles, ~ .x$beaks))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  location eagles           beaks    
     <dbl> <list>           <list>   
1        1 <tibble [2 × 2]> <chr [2]>
2        2 <tibble [2 × 2]> <chr [2]>
```